# Jquery can't pass variable through function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//var audit_to_del;
//var type;
//var option_selected;
//var progress;
 function redirect(audit_type) { 
           var page;
                switch(audit_type){
                    case 'Simple 123': 
                          page = 'smeg';
                          break; 
                }//end switch
            return page;
       }

    $('#audit_summary_list_div').on("click", ".go_btn", function(e){ 
         var audit_to_del = $(this).prev('.audit_to_del').val();
         var type = $(this).closest('tr').find('.audit_type').text();
         var option_selected = $(this).closest('td').prev().find('.option_select').val();
         var progress = $(this).closest('tr').find('.progress').text();

         var location = redirect(type);

     alert(location);
   });
});
```

If I pass a literal value through the function it works and returns 'smeg'

```
var location = redirect('Simple 123');
```

If I `alert(type)` the value is correctly shown as `Simple 123`

If I try to use

```
var location = redirect(type);
```

I get an undefined error

I have tried created global variables and then using them in the function

Comment: It probably just doesn't get into any switch case.

Comment: can it be it cant find: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.audit_type')` so that when u execute `.text();` you get `undefined`?

Comment: The function works as it should, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/znFV7/

Comment: Thanks everyone, the issue has been resolved, it was caused by white space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text has white-space in it making the condition false. Try that :

```
var location = redirect($.trim(type));
```

Comment: Thank you, I would never had worked that out, I'll accept when it lets me

Comment: @tatty27 glad it worked, in the futur, always keep in mind that function like `text()` or `html()` also keep indentation of your code